# How to limit character on title Blogger

Tags: blogger

I have a Blogger blog and I would like to reduce the length of title.

"Find out the new Iphone 6 in my showroom" should be " Find out the new Iphone 6..."

Is there any way ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use CSS property Elipsis to limit the title

Here is a page which may help you http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-overflow.asp

Answer (score 0):

you can set title length in index pages by javascript. Paste this code before . You can change the maximum length 30.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
$(".title").each(function(){
    if($(this).text().length>30)
    {$(this).text($(this).text().substr(0, 30)+'...');}
});    
//]]>
</script>
```